# Sphinx autodoc: permalinks not generated due to ifconfig

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I am writing documentation to my Python package and I am using sphinx together with autodoc extension. I would like to have two versions of documentation: user documentation and developer documentation. The overlap between those two is quite large, so I am generating them based on one source. Parts specific for only one output are included via ifconfig extension.

Now I would like to have two versions of API specification, one basic for user and one detailed for developer:

```
API
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

.. ifconfig:: develdoc

    .. autoclass:: settings.Settings    
        :members:
        :private-members:
        :special-members:


.. ifconfig:: not develdoc

    .. autoclass:: settings.Settings    
        :members:
```

In general it works fine, but there is one problem. In the document generated by the second directive (in this case: user documentation) there are entries for class and its methods, but they don't have HTML anchors associated with them. In other parts of the document links to `Settings` are active, but they lead to nowhere (nothing happens on click).

If I switch the order to:

```
API
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

.. ifconfig:: not develdoc

    .. autoclass:: settings.Settings    
        :members:


.. ifconfig:: develdoc

    .. autoclass:: settings.Settings    
        :members:
        :private-members:
        :special-members:
```

the anchors in the developer documentation are only for private and special members. So it looks like the first ifconfig "reserves" all its methods and when they are repeated in the second ifconfig something bad happens and no anchors are generated.

I suppose this is rather a bug than a feature :) Anyway, does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: I found a solution avoiding the usage of ``ifconfig``. In my ``conf.py`` I set ``autodoc_default_flags`` to be either ``['members']`` or ``['members','private-members','special-members']`` depending on the value of ``develdoc``. Solves the problem, but makes it a global thing.